# How to start all stop SQL Server Services using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to start all stop SQL Server services using C#?

I am using this code but it is not working properly and show following error message :

> Cannot open MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service on computer '.'.

Code:

```
public string RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    string status= string.Empty;

    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

    try
    {
         int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
         TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
         //service.Stop();
         //service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

         // count the rest of the timeout
         int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
         timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

         service.Start();
         service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

         status = service.Status.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = ex.Message;
    }

    return status;
}
```

I want to use SQL Server service in window service to check if SQL Server is running or not. If it not running, then I want to start server first and then do next work.

Comment: but service allready exist in my computer

Comment: I guess there is also an InnerException present, ain't it? And there will most likely stand something like: "Access is denied". So are you running this code with the sufficient rights (started VisualStudio as administrator)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - **IF** the service exists, and **IF** you have the permission to start and stop services (running as `Administrator`), then this code should work just fine. Debug some more, check if you get any exception, and if so - inspect **ALL** the info the exception returns (including any `.InnerException`) to see what's really going on.....